# How to include a reg exp into a switch case string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, switch-statement

I would like to compress different urls with the use of a switch case and regular expressions.

That's the code I created but it seems not working efficiently:

```
url = window.location.pathname;
switch(url){
    case /\/(en|fr|de|es)\/page1\/: myvar="page1"; break;
    case /\/(en|fr|de|es)\/page2\/: myvar="page2"; break;
    ...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What about a regex to take the `pageN` and set it to `myvar`? If it is possible, could you give an url example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `case` will evaluate the supplied expression as boolean and take that action if necessary. The only real way I can see of doing this using switch case is:

```
let url = window.location.pathname;

switch (true) {
  case /^mytest$/.test(url):
    ...
    break;
}
```

That being said I really wouldn't recommend doing it this way at all.

I'm not entirely sure what it is that you need from the original string, but it looks like it would just be easier to strip the locale segment out and have the left over as the page?